# Issue on Loading a Div entire content to New Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/dn7ha8mm/)  and let me know why I am not able to load the `#source` div into `#target` div?

```
<div id="source">
    <div class="source-inn"><a>A</a></div>
    <div class="source-inn"><p>B</p></div>
    <div class="source-inn"><span>C</span></div>
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
<script> 
$( "#source" ).load( "#target" );
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dn7ha8mm/2/ works for me

Comment: .load() is for ajax: you call a server that returns HTML that gets inserted in the selector. What do you mean by "load the #source div into #target div?"

Comment: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use .load() here because that is to **load data from the server** and place the returned HTML into the matched element ([doc for .load is here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)).

I Suggest to use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) elements like that :

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/rc9kgekc/

```
$('#target').append($('#source').children());
```

The DOM result after that will be:

```
<div id="source">

<div id="target">
    <div class="source-inn"><a>A</a></div>
    <div class="source-inn"><p>B</p></div>
    <div class="source-inn"><span>C</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**BUT**, if you want DOM result to be like that:

```
<div id="target">
    <div id="source">
         <div class="source-inn"><a>A</a></div>
         <div class="source-inn"><p>B</p></div>
         <div class="source-inn"><span>C</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you will use it without .children() as bellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/aywww7r7/

```
  $('#target').append($('#source'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want to append the div to the source like this:

```
$( "#source" ).append( $("#target") );
```

note that the css won't apply to the target since the target div doesnt have the same class.